# How can I create a class that is a vector of another class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, vector, playing-cards

Thanks for reading my question.

I'm trying to begin writing a program that uses a deck of cards, because I want to learn about using classes. I decided to create a class that stores a suit and a value, like so:

```c++
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H

class Card {        
    public:
        //here are the individual card values
        int _suit;
        int _value;
        Card(int suit, int value);
};

#endif
```

```c++
#include "card.h"

//define suits
const int spades = 0;
const int clubs = 1;
const int hearts = 2;
const int diamonds = 3;
//define face cards
const int jack = 11;
const int queen = 12;
const int king = 13;
const int ace = 14;

Card::Card(int suit, int value){
    _suit = suit;
    _value = value;
}
```

I then decided to create a deck class, and in that class initialize my cards by assigning a value from 0-3 (suit) and then a value from 2-14 (ranking of card). I also add the cards into a vector that I defined to hold them, like so:

```c++
#ifndef DECK_H
#define DECK_H

#include <vector>

class Deck {
    public:
        std::vector<Card> _deck(51);
        Deck();
};

#endif
```

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "card.h"
#include "deck.h"

const int all_suits = 4 - 1;
const int all_values = 14;

Deck::Deck(){
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j <= all_suits; ++j) {
        //begin with 2 because card can't have value 0
        for (int k = 2; k <= all_values; ++k) {
            _deck[i] = Card(j, k);
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

This somehow gives me issues when I try to test the program like so:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "card.h"
#include "deck.h"

int main() {
    Deck new_deck = Deck();
    std::cout << new_deck._deck[4]._value;
  return 0;
}
```

The following errors show up when I try to run the code:

```html
In file included from main.cpp:6:
./deck.h:8:27: error: expected parameter declarator
                std::vector<Card> _deck(51);
                                        ^
./deck.h:8:27: error: expected ')'
./deck.h:8:26: note: to match this '('
                std::vector<Card> _deck(51);
                                       ^
main.cpp:22:24: error: reference to non-static member function must be called; did you mean to call it with no arguments?
        std::cout << new_deck._deck[4]._value;
                     ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
                                   ()
3 errors generated.
In file included from deck.cpp:8:
./deck.h:8:27: error: expected parameter declarator
                std::vector<Card> _deck(51);
                                        ^
./deck.h:8:27: error: expected ')'
./deck.h:8:26: note: to match this '('
                std::vector<Card> _deck(51);
                                       ^
deck.cpp:18:4: error: reference to non-static member function must be called; did you mean to call it with no arguments?
                        _deck[i] = Card(j, k);
                        ^~~~~
                             ()
3 errors generated.
```

Honestly, I'm not quite sure what's going on. I pretty closely followed an example of classes I saw online. If anyone could help me find the problem, that would be much appreciated. Sorry, I'm a little new to this, and may have made some silly mistakes. I really appreciate your time and patience in reading this and helping me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies with the declaration of `_deck`:

```
class Deck {
    public:
        std::vector<Card> _deck(51);
```

Here you are trying to declare `_deck` and call a constructor, but you can not do so from a class member initialiser. It's possible to do this for data members with no constructors, for example:

```
class Deck {
    public:
        int no_of_cards = 51;
        std::vector<Card> _deck;
```

You will need to use your constructor to initialise `_deck` (much like you're already doing:

```
Deck::Deck() {
    _deck.reserve(51);
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j <= all_suits; ++j) {
        //begin with 2 because card can't have value 0
        for (int k = 2; k <= all_values; ++k) {
            _deck.push_back(Card(j, k));
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

And leave your declaration of `_deck` as:

```
class Deck {
    public:
        std::vector<Card> _deck;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it really doesn't seem to like this, and is giving me many errors. Is there another way I might initialize _deck?

Comment: Ah, it was _deck.reserve(51), not deck.resize. Thank you the technical explanation, even if the code was a few letters off!

Comment: Ah my apologies! I had already been foiled by the lack of constructor in `Card`. Yes you're right, though the call to `reserve` isn't necessary, but you do need to call `push_back` to place the cards (regardless)

Comment: Also, you may want to remove the [i] after deck, in your answer, since _deck[i] is a Card, not the vector _deck, in case someone else has this issue. Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: Thanks, I rectified that

Comment: You can provide a default initializer for any data member. It's just that round braces aren't supported. You'd need uniform initialization syntax `_deck{51};`